# Can I use 1/4 inch copper tubing with a compression needle valve to run propane to a gas light?

Tags: gas, propane

Can I use 1/4 inch copper tubing with a compression needle valve to run propane to a gas light? I am worried that gas would leak from the compression fitting

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to look into your local code to find out if it's approved. Where I live, compression fittings aren't allowed for gas but flared fittings are. If you're not sure, you should contact a licensed gas fitter in your area.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should hire a qualified gasfitter. A properly connected compression fitting will not leak, but there's no point in DIY-ing gas lines if you're not 100% sure of your ability to get a leak free connection. Your propane supplier will usually either have people on staff, or know who to recommend locally.